# Paypal: How does xclick-auto-billing work?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="dummy@example.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-auto-billing" /> <!-- _xclick-subscriptions works here -->
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="12" />
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M" />
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF" name="bn">
</form>
```

I was trying to find out what the differences are between `_xclick-subscriptions` and `_xclick-auto-billing`. Above form works when the `cmd` value is `_xclick-subscriptions`. However, when I replace it with `_xclick-auto-billing`, Paypal returns an error page saying "item amount" is incorrect. I check [Paypal's documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/#technical-variables) but there isn't much explanation or example about `_xclick-auto-billing`. So how should I use this `cmd` and what are the differences?

Answer (score 0):

In general, auto-billing should not be used unless you are able to generate a sample auto billing button via https://www.paypal.com/buttons

When doing so, uncheck the option in section 2 to save the button at PayPal. When viewing the generated code, click the option to remove the code protection. Then you will have sample working HTML that you can adapt to your needs.

If you cannot create such a button, it is because your account does not support it. Subscriptions are much more widely supported and should be used instead, generally speaking.

Instead of the old-style Subscribe button, consider the new Smart Payment Buttons which use plans and products as a base and offer a much more modern checkout experience. See https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans